# Are these bash statements all equivalent?

Tags: bash

I just discovered this great site.  I was reading bash tagged posts when the following question entered my mind:

This code:

```
var=$RANDOM

var1=$[ $var % 13 ]
echo "var1 = $var1"

var2=$( $var % 13 )
echo "var2 = $var2"

var3=$(( $var % 13 ))
echo "var3 = $var3"

var4=`expr $var % 13` # Note revised from original post by adding the expr
echo "var4 = $var4"
```

Produces this output:

```
var1 = 7
./question: line 7: 23225: command not found
var2 = 
var3 = 7
var4 = 7
```

So only the var2 statement does not work.  My question is: is it only a matter of personal choice as to which of the other three should be used or are there other considerations that should be taken into account?

(I've edited this question extensively after seeing replies.  Hope I'm doing this the right way.)

Comment: I have run them now and I edited the original question with the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$[]` and `$(())` versions are essentially interchangeable, except that not all shells support `$[]`, so don't use it -- use `$(())` instead.  Also, in both of these forms, variables used in the expression will be automatically expanded, so you don't need to use `$` inside them:

```
var=$RANDOM
echo $var             # prints 7482 (in my example run)
echo $[ $var % 13 ]   # prints 7
echo $[ var % 13 ]    # prints 7
echo $(( $var % 13 )) # prints 7
echo $(( var % 13 ))  # prints 7
```

`expr` is actually a command which does expression evaluation -- it has most of the same capabilities as the builtin expression evaluation, but without some of the niceties.  For instance, you must use `$` to expand variables, and must escape any operators that the shell would treat as special characters (e.g. `<`, `>`, `|`, etc):

```
expr $var % 13        # prints 7
echo `expr $var % 13` # prints 7, just by a less direct route
```

`$()` is totally different -- it doesn't do arithmetic evaluation, it runs its contents as a command.  In fact, it's almost the same as backquotes (except that it is easier to read, and has much cleaner syntax, so I always use it instead of backquotes):

```
echo $(expr $var % 13) # prints 7, same as with backquotes
```

And just to make this more complicated, let me add some more options:

```
(( var5 = var % 13 )) # This is an arithmetic statement (that happens to contain an assignment)
echo $var5            # prints 7
let "var6 = var % 13" # Another form for pretty much the same thing
echo $var6            # prints 7

declare -i var7  # declare var7 as an integer...
var7="var % 13"  #  to force values assigned to it to be evaluated
echo $var7       # prints 7
```

So what should you use?  I'd go with `var3=$(( var % 13 ))` for maximum compatibility and (IMHO) clean syntax.

Comment: Great answer, Gordon.  So complete and even extending the question with other options.  I will use var3=$(( var % 13 )) from now on.  Now I'll go off to figure out how to award you your point.

Comment: I guess that the only way to award points is by voting it up.  I tried but I don't have enough reputation to vote!  I only have 11 and you need 15.

Comment: @grok: I'm glad it was helpful.  Since you asked the original question, you should be able to accept an answer (click on the check box outline to the left of the answer) even if you can't vote yet.

Comment: I clicked the check green and it moved your post to the top but it still won't let me vote you up due to not having 15 reputation.

Comment: I finally accumulated some rep and was able to give you a point.  Hurray!

Answer (score 2):

The `$[…]` and `$((…))` are exactly equivalent. However, the `$[…]` form is a deprecated bash and zsh extension; the `$((…))` form is [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04).

The `expr` form is roughly equivalent, but it calls the external program [`expr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/expr.html). In the old days, shells didn't have many built-in capabilities, in particular no arithmetic, and so one would use `expr` for arithmetic. Nowadays there's not much use for `expr`.

`$( $var % 13 )` is just broken, it tries to call `$var` (or more precisely, the first word of it) as a command name.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't have included $( $var % 13 ).  I will use $((…)) due to it being standard.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid command

```
var=$( $var % 13 )
```

**Valid command** but prefer `$(( var % 13 ))`

```
var=$(( $var % 13 ))
```

Invalid command

```
var=$var % 13
```

**Outcome:** So out of all only `$(( var % 13 ))` is the valid way to get the modulo of `$var` by 13.

**Update**

After your edits I would say use either `var1` or `var3` way of getting modulo calculated. `expr` is an external program and its better to use bash's internal utility to get the same job done.

Comment: Sorry, everyone.  I've bungled my first question.  I'm going off to try each of these myself as I should have done before posting.  Then I'll come back and figure out how to post code.

Comment: After your edits I would say use either `var1` or `var3` way of getting modulo calculated. `expr` is an external program and its better to use bash's internal utility to get the same job done.

Comment: I used to do a lot of sh scripts but that was 19 years ago so I am out of touch with the new additions.  I think that 19 years ago only the expr way was available but I will stop using it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
((var%=13))
```

is another way, a shortcut for var=((var%13))

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out.  I had no idea that you could use assignment operators like that.

Comment: However, when I try (( var3%=13 )); echo "var3 = $var3" I always get zero.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: `var3=99; (( var3%=13 )); echo $var3` echos `8` for me in bash. `GNU bash, Version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Maybe you never initialized var3?

Comment: Brilliant observation!  I was not initializing var3.  Now I'm using: var3=var; (( var3%=13 )); echo "var3 = $var3"
and it works.  Sorry that I doubted you.